# Is it possible to use private unicode positions in encoding files?

Tags: font-encodings, otftotfm

I am currently in the process of converting a large icon font into something usable for LaTeX. So far everything worked well, I wrote a script that converts the accompanied documentation into encoding files and then I run otftotfm. However the font makes use of the number space above 0xFFFF, so there are also characters in the range of 0xF0000 and above. I tried to just write that, into an encoding file, like:

```
[...]
/uniEB0C
/uniEB0D
/uniEB0E
/uniEB0F
/uniF0000
/uniF0001
/uniF0002
/uniF0003
[...]
```

However it seems when I run `otftotfm` over it, that it ignores every line after `/uniEB0F`. So my question is: Is there a way to use the unicode spaces F0000 and forward?

Edit: I think I understand now that the encoding should be UTF16, right? So 0xF0000 would be 0xDB80 0xDC00, right? But how can I write that in an encoding file? /uniDB80uniDC00? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For codepoints outside of the BMP (aka. above U+10000), you have to use the `/u` prefix and not `/uni`. You should not encode them in UTF-16 (or some other encoding).

So you get

```
[...]
/uEB0C
/uEB0D
/uEB0E
/uEB0F
/uF0000
/uF0001
/uF0002
/uF0003
[...]
```

(You could also keep using `/uni` for the smaller codepoints, but IMO it's better to be consistent)

These rules are derived from the glyph name format used for the Adobe glyph list which is documented in https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/agl-specification.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was the solution! Is there any documentation available?

Comment: @TobiBS I added a reference to the AGL spec.